# No JSON data displayed on php script

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have json data which looks as follows:

```
{
"firmware": [
    {
        "Request": "/Firmware/samsung",
        "Count": "2954"
    },
    {
        "Request": "/Firmware/apple",
        "Count": "2954"
    }
],
"exe": [
    {
        "Request": "/applications/appstore.exe",
        "Count": "4482"
    }
]    
}
```

I am trying to read it via PHP script and display it. But not seeing any data. The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/json/softwarelogs.js"></script>
<fieldset class="light" style="width: 60%; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; float: left;" >
<legend>Top Firmware Downloads</legend>
<div class="statlist" id="topFirmware"> </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="light" style="width: 60%; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; float: left;">
<legend>Top EXE Downloads</legend>
<div class="statlist" id="exe"> </div>
</fieldset>

<script>
   var htmlString = "<ol>";
   $.each(firmware, function(i, item) {
    htmlString = htmlString + "<li>" + item.Request;
    });

    $('#topFirmware').html(htmlString + "</ol>");
    htmlString = "<ol>";
    $.each(exe, function(i, item) {
    htmlString = htmlString + "<li>" + item.Request;
    });

    $('#exe').html(htmlString + "</ol>");

$.fn.digits = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
})

</script>
```

I am fairly new to PHP programming so not sure about the arrangement and syntax. Please correct me and guide me if something is wrong and if you need more information. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In your code there is no use of that json

Comment: Please see the edited php script. The json data is fetched via url. Thanks!!

Comment: There is not a single character of php code in this question...

Comment: @Cerbrus - The file is saved as .php. Thanks!!

Comment: That doesn't magically make the contents php. This is just html and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *directly* load (and use) JSON data by including it via script tags, try this instead:

```
$.getJSON('/json/softwarelogs.js', function(data) {
   var htmlString = "<ol>";
   $.each(data.firmware, function(i, item) {
    htmlString = htmlString + "<li>" + item.Request;
    });

    $('#topFirmware').html(htmlString + "</ol>");
    htmlString = "<ol>";
    $.each(exe, function(i, item) {
    htmlString = htmlString + "<li>" + item.Request;
    });

    $('#exe').html(htmlString + "</ol>");

    $.fn.digits = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
    })
});
```

Comment: _"You can't load (and use) JSON data by including it via script tags"_ Eh, yes you can. If you add `var x =` in front of it, but then, technically, you'd be loading a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Rob - Should I insert it into the script tags or create a seperate PHP page? Thanks.

Comment: No data is yet coming. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @deep it depends, if your json is stored in a php variable then in you don't need the `getJSON`, just do something like `var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;`, if it's an array or object: `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`, then you can use it in your js. If your server outputs JSON at a url, then the `getJSON` method is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your json is saved in a variable like

**Note:-** If its a simple string then you could change is to json using `JSON.parse(jsonString);`

```
var jsData={
"firmware": [
    {
        "Request": "/Firmware/samsung",
        "Count": "2954"
    },
    {
        "Request": "/Firmware/apple",
        "Count": "2954"
    }
],
"exe": [
    {
        "Request": "/applications/appstore.exe",
        "Count": "4482"
    }
]    
};
```

Now change the following statement

```
$.each(firmware, function(i, item)
```

**to**

```
$.each(jsData.firmware, function(i, item)
```

Comment: No data is yet coming? Any suggestions. Thanks.